# form submit with setTimeout not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, submit

I am submitting a form based on a condition and a setTimeout statement in submit event handler, however the form is still getting submitted even when I put return false in setTimeout function.

```js
bool = true;
$('.form-example').submit(function(e) { 
    //some_stuff where I am get a value true or false in variable bool
    setTimeout(function () {      
        if(bool) {    
            console.log('form shouldnt submit coz the following statement is return false');
            return false; 
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }, 1000);           
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="post" class="form-example">
        <div class="form-example">
            <label for="name">Enter your name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required> 
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_user">
    </form>
```

Comment: just add `e.preventDefault()` at the start of submit method

Comment: The `submit` event is not paused just because you call `setTimeout` in one of its handlers. Have a look at `.preventDefault()`

Comment: @SuperDJ thats not the point, why is form getting submitted when I have return false statement there ?

Comment: @Andreas I did put e.preventDefault(), but I was not able to submit the form when validation is true, form was submitting with no values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
bool = false;
$('.form-example').submit(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    //some_stuff where I am get a value true or false in variable bool
        if(bool) {    
            alert('Not submit');
            return false; 
        }else{
            alert('Submit');
            $(this).unbind("submit").submit();
            return true;
        }         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" class="form-example">
        <div class="form-example">
            <label for="name">Enter your name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required> 
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_user">
    </form>
```

Comment: Submit is an event. So if you want to stop the submission then you have to use event prevent.

Comment: if bool is false form should submit again , how to do that

Comment: Check the snippet. If bool is false then it is submitting the form.

Comment: its not submitting the form, its just alerting submit lol

Comment: Check the updated snippet.

Comment: the problem was totally different, jQuery does not submit the value of submit button, and thats why I was not getting value of submit button in php, I fixed it with getting the value of username element in php. Your answer helped too, the `unbind('submit')` statement worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `e.preventDefault()` only when you don't want to submit form.

```js
var bool = false;
$('.form-example').submit(function(e) { 
    //some_stuff where I am get a value true or false in variable bool
    if(bool) {    
        alert('Not submit');
         e.preventDefault();
         return false; 
    } else {
         alert('Submit');
        return true;
    }         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" class="form-example">
        <div class="form-example">
            <label for="name">Enter your name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required> 
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_user">
    </form>
```